# file_get_contents for insertion in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a two pages in my website, one is named "new_account.php" and the other is "visitor.php". The user can choose to create a new account for themselves or just go with a visitor account.

When the user picks "visitor" I make a request to "new_account.php" to create a temporary account with a random username and password, to be deleted later when the user is done. I'm using `file_get_contents` for the request, since the page returns the user hash which I use to automatically login the user.

This is "visitor.php":

```
$url = getBaseUrl().'new-account.php';
$data = array(
    'name' => $tempName, 
    'character-name' => $tempCharacterName, 
    'gender' => $tempGender, 
    'age' => $tempAge, 
    'parent-email' => $tempParentEmail, 
    'password' => $tempPassword, 
    'password-confirmation' => $tempPassword,
    'temporary' => TRUE
);

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($result);

if($result != "error") {
    User::loginUser($result, TRUE, $conn);
    User::ifUserLoggedRedirect('game.php',$conn);
}
```

My problem is that, while the request is successful and a new random user is inserted in the database, when User::loginUser tries to query the user data using the hash returned by `file_get_contents` (such as the user icon or user name) I'm getting an empty result set.

`User::loginUser` is this:

```
public static function loginUser($userHash, $temporary, $conn) {
        if(User::isAnyLogged($conn))
            User::logout($conn);

        User::safeSessionStart();

        $result = $conn->prepare('SELECT p.screen_name, pi.url, p.id FROM player as p, player_icon as pi WHERE p.user_hash=? AND pi.id = p.player_icon_id');
        $result->bind_param('s',$userHash);
        $result->execute();
        $res = $result->get_result();

        if($res->num_rows == 0) {
            die("Invalid user with hash ".$userHash);
        }

        $user_info = $res->fetch_assoc();

        $_SESSION['user'] = new User($userHash, $temporary, $user_info['screen_name'], $user_info['url'], $user_info['id']);

        setcookie('userHash',$userHash);
        setcookie('temporary',$temporary ? '1' : '0' );

        return $_SESSION['user'];
    }
```

And the call always dies with an invalid hash, but if I query the user from phpmyadmin using the hash the user is actually there. Going through the normal registration by accessing "new_account.php" also works.

The first thing I tried was closing and reopenning the connection after getting the result from `file_get_contents` but that didn't work. Using `mysqli::refresh` also didn't work. I tried moving the login part of the code to the "new_account.php" but apparently I also can't set the `$_SESSION` from a request using `file_get_contents`.

I also could solve this by copying the new account code to the visitor page, but I would rather keep the account creation in a single page. Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

You should use require_once to include the new-account.PHP

This way, you can use the code of the included file as if it were in the file from where you include it.

Comment: new_account.php also has a bunch of HTML, since it is the account creation page. It wouldnt be really straightforward to do that. I could transfer the account creation to a function and call ot from both places though... hmm

Comment: You should always separate concerns.  Split up your actual "business logic" and your presentation layer. This way, you have more control over both without having huge side effects.